# Locate the ylabel without cutting in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have this Gnuplot code that shows two lines.

```
set terminal pngcairo dashed font 'DroidSerif'
set output "size_tree.png"

set xrange [10:100]
set yrange [10:10000]

set xtics font ", 15"
set ytics font ", 15"
set key font ",12"
set key top left box
set title "Trees" font ",20"

set xlabel "Node size" font ",18"

set ylabel "Communication overhead\n(contexts)" font ",18"
set logscale y
set format y "10^%T"

set nokey
set key invert   

set style line 1 lw 3 lc rgb '#000000' ps 2   pt 6
set style line 2 lw 3 lc rgb '#000000' ps 2   pt 7

plot "data.txt"       using 1:2  title "singles"                  ls 1 w lp , \
""                    using 1:3  title "aggregates"               ls 2 w lp
```

The issue is that the xlegend and the chart is too close. I used offset to control the location of the label, but this gives me cut off in ylabel.

```
set ylabel "Communication overhead\n(contexts)" font ",18"  offset -1,0
```

[image]

How can I offset the ylabel without cutting?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19276013/2604213

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `set lmargin <margin>` command to expand the canvas so that the offset label fits completely.